# Unit Tests for designs that use notifications

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ios4, ocunit, observer-pattern

I'm having difficulty testing some logic that uses notifications. I've read about [enforcing that particular `NSNotifications` are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062191/enforcing-that-a-class-posts-a-particular-nsnotification), but that doesn't really address the problem I'm seeing.

`[SomeObject PerformAsyncOperation]` creates an `NSURLRequest` and sets itself as the response delegate. Depending on the content of the response, `SomeObject` posts a success or failure `NSNotification` to the default `NSNotificationCenter`.

The problem with my test is that after `PerformAsyncOperation` is called, the test doesn't wait for the response to be sent. Instead, it continues on with the assert - which fails, because the request/response hasn't had time to be sent/received/parsed.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)testMethod {
    SomeObject *x = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(success:)
                                            name:SomeObjectSuccess
                                          object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(failure:)
                                            name:SomeObjectFailure
                                          object:nil];

    operationCompleted = false; // declared in .h

    [x PerformAsyncOperation:@"parameter"];

    STAssertTrue(operationCompleted , @"Operation has completed.");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:SomeObjectSuccess object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:SomeObjectFailure object:nil];

    [x release];
}

-(void) failure:(NSNotification *) notification {
   operationCompleted = true;
   NSLog(@"Received failure message.");
}

-(void) success:(NSNotification *) notification {
   operationCompleted = true;
   NSLog(@"Received success message.");
}
```

I've tried sleeping the thread after the call to `PerformAsyncOperation`, as well as an empty `while (!operationCompleted)` loop. Neither works - sleeping the thread still fails the assert, and the while loop never exits. I've also tried moving the asserts into `success:` and `failure:`, but because OCUnit expects each method to be a test method, it just executes all three methods immediately and quits (without waiting for the `NSURLRequest`'s response, which is the whole point of the exercise!).

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem you face is not notifications, which are synchronous. Rather, it is that you are firing off an asynchronous operation. To make this a repeatable test, you need to resynchronize things.

```
NSTimeInterval timeout = 2.0;   // Number of seconds before giving up
NSTimeInterval idle = 0.01;     // Number of seconds to pause within loop
BOOL timedOut = NO;

NSDate *timeoutDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeout];
while (!timedOut && !operationCompleted)
{
    NSDate *tick = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:idle];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:tick];
    timedOut = ([tick compare:timeoutDate] == NSOrderedDescending);
    [tick release];
}
[timeoutDate release];
```

Beyond this point, you know that either the operation completed, or the test timed out.

Comment: I would highly recommend using an assertion framework that provides syntax sugar for you. For example, I use Specta https://github.com/specta/specta/tree/0.3-wip, which provides a function called `waitUntil(^{})`. You place your code within the block and if it doesn't complete within a configurable amount of time (10s by default) then the test fails. Otherwise it succeeds.

Comment: Yes, a number of testing frameworks provide this. Recent additions include Apple's XCTest and my OCHamcrest.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity reasons, and if possible, use the synchronous network requests.

```
- (void)testExample
{
    [self measureBlock:^{

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWith...];

        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:nil];

        XCTAssertEqual(response.statusCode,200);

        // process the data from response ... call the delegate methods or whatever

        NSObject *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                         error:nil];
        XCTAssertTrue([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);
    }];
}
```